# Some text replaccement issues. Please advise

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, sed

I'm new at bash scripting and I have a problem. I want to replace one line in a file with another one. This is my file:

```
/home/iosub/linux/fis2 b7c839bf081421804e15c51d65a6f8fc -  
/home/iosub/linux/e212CIosub/doi 7edd241b1f05a9ea346c085b8c9e95c5 -    
/home/iosub/linux/e212CIosub/test2 7edd241b1f05a9ea346c085b8c9e95c5 -    
/home/iosub/linux/e212CIosub/xab ed4940ef42ec8f72fa8bdcf506a13f3d -    
/home/iosub/linux/e212CIosub/test1 8af599cfb361efb9cd4c2ad7b4c4e53a -    
/home/iosub/linux/e212CIosub/xaa 8cf57351b5fc952ec566ff865c6ed6bd -    
/home/iosub/linux/e212CIosub/test3 74420c2c4b90871894aa51be38d33f2c -
```

Without the blank lines. I want to replace a line with another one.

```
for example  /home/iosub/linux/e212CIosub/test1 8af599cfb361efb9cd4c2ad7b4c4e53a -
with         /home/iosub/linux/e212CIosub/test1 d2199e312ecd00ff5f9c12b7d54c97f1 -
```

I have  `/home/iosub/linux/e212CIosub/test1` in a variable and the new code in another variable.

I know that I must use sed. How can I do it?

I've tried a lot of combinations like:

```
sed "/$1/d"  cont > cont2;
```

where  `$1` is  `/home/iosub/linux/e212CIosub/test1`

And after that I concatenate the new string to the file. This places the new line at the end of the file, it would  be a good solution, if it would work . . . But it doesn't.It gives an error:  `sed: -e expression #1, char 5: extra characters after command`

I've also tried the replacement method, but I didn't get any result.

Any solution would be good. Thank's

Comment: It's not clear where your value 'd2199e312ecd00ff5f9c12b7d54c97f1' is coming from. It is not in the sample data you provided. It might also help to include more of the processing that you are doing after the `sed "@$1@d" ...` . Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed "s@$1@$var@g" -i filename
```

This will replace all occurences of $1 with $var in file *filename* inplace.

Answer (score 4):

**edit** added '' in front of @ chars for initial regex delimiters

when you have a '/' char in your search pattern, it breaks the use of that character ('/') as a reg-exp delimiter. Use a Regex delimiter that is NOT in your regex, i.e.

```
sed "\@$1@d" cont > cont2
```

Then continue with your processing.

But given your example, why don't you do something like

```
sed "s\@\($1\)(.*$)@\1 $2 -@" cont > cont2
```

This matches your value from $1, essentially deletes the text after your $1 value, and prints the $1 value followed by a space, your $2 value (d2....), a space and the ending '-' character.

**Edit** (Finally), I'll mention that some legacy Unix sed's (aix in particular) seem to not accept escaping the regex delimiter char (but I don't have access to a system to verify that now). In that case, you have to escape all of the any-and-all '/'s in your regex search pattern, like `\/home\/iosub\/linux\/e212CIosub\/test1`, yikes!